# C++ Function Call very slow

Tags: c++, performance, function, call

I have written a recursive Branch&Cut algorithm, and am now trying to speed up the execution. I have noticed something very curious though: At one point I call a function to compute some vector of vectors. Using clock(), I measured the time spent on this function in the file where it is called as well as in the function itself. Visualization:

```
tic
foo(args);
time1 = toc
```

and

```
void foo(args) {
  tic
  //do stuff
  time2 = toc
}
```

My problem is that time1 is about 3 times larger than time2, which to me makes no sense at all. The actual function has a lot of arguments and is the following:

```
void allcomb( std::vector<int> &Vin, 
              std::vector<int> &Vprev, 
              Graph F, 
              int t, 
              const int n, 
              const int numofdests, 
              int Time_hor,
              std::vector<int> &truckdest, 
              std::vector<int> &truck_dest_index, 
              std::vector<int> &descroflabel, 
              std::vector<int> &labelofdescr, 
              std::vector<std::vector<double> > &short_path_time,  
              std::vector<std::vector<double> > &short_path_fuel, 
              double eta, 
              std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >& next_hub,
              std::vector<std::pair<double,double> >& distanceto_next_hub, 
              std::vector<std::vector<int> >& Choices )
```

I pass all the vectors by reference to avoid copying them, but maybe I am missing something? Or is it just generally slow to frequently call a function with that many arguments?
Also, entering the function uses more time than exiting it, maybe that's important.

If you need more information, please tell me.
Thanks and cheers, Christoph

---

The boost Graph object was the problem, thanks for spotting it :) runtime lowered by a factor of 10, perfect!

Comment: That function may be taking a couple of arguments more than the legal limit in your jurisdiction.

Comment: How large is that `Graph` object?

Comment: If you have a function with so many parameters, you probably missed some.

Comment: Are you calling foo recursively?

Comment: If you need to pass so many arguments, you're doing it wrong. That's what abstraction is for: that you do not need to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Although not so good design passing many arguments to a function will not slow things down significantly(assuming you pass everything by refference). However I notice you pass copies to some stuff in particular `Graph F` and that seems to be something that can be big.

Comment: stare at your code long enough and you go blind... it's a boost Graph and it might indeed be the problem, thanks for spotting this!

Comment: +1 for actually looking at the arguments and not just reading it as `void allcomb(bunch of arguments go here)`, like I did :)

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but:

```
   time2 = toc
}
```

I'm guessing the culprit is the `}`. Say you have something like:

```
void foo(args) {
  tic
  SomeReallyExpensiveObject x;
  time2 = toc
}
```

in which case you're not timing the destruction. If you have loads of vectors inside in automatic storage, their destruction could take a long time.

Try this experiment:

```
void foo(args) {
  tic
  {
     //do stuff
  }
  time2 = toc
}
```

If the measured times are brought closer, that's the problem.